# use scale_fill_manual in R for a specific layer of layers in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, aes, geom-point

I have trouble for plotting my raster and some points as sf object over that. I use `aes(color=...)` to assign color to different types of my points. But I want to change the colours to specific ones like red and blue and yellow. also I can't use `scale_fill_manual` because my raster layer's colours which is in first layer, shouldn't be changed. Is there any solution for this problem?
thanks in advance

```
geom_raster(data=dem2,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=elevation))+
geom_sf(data=mypoint,aes(shape=Type,colour=ranges))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale

Answer (score 0):

The `fill` parameter inside `aes` wich you can manipulate manually using `scale_fill_manual`  works perfectly with polygons or raster data. But, when you need to color points
or simple lines, the `color`  parameter inside `aes` is prefered. Said that, if you want to assing different colors to your points, `use scale_color_manual`, this shouldnt interfer in your raster color.

Answer (score -1):

package "ggnewscale" will work in this problem. It allows to use different scale for color in one plot.